# Raw mysql statement with bindings in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to run a raw mysql statement to Laravel's query builder, to create a new MySQL user.
Of course, I make use of parameter bindings to prevent injections.

My current query won't work in Laravel 4 of 5:

```
DB::statement( 'CREATE USER \':username\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY \':password\';', array('username' => 'johndoe', 'password' => 'secret') );
```

No errors, nothing is happening.
When I ask for the QueryLog this is on my screen:

```
        [query] => CREATE USER ':username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ':password';
        [bindings] => Array
            (
                [username] => johndoe
                [password] => secret
            )

        [time] => 0.31
```

So it look's okay, but the actual query isn't working...
What's wrong here?

## EDIT

Database Log Output:

```
      204 Prepare   CREATE USER '?'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '?'
      204 Close stmt    
      204 Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like DDL queries are officially not supported by the most database servers. Check: [Can we use DDL Commands in a prepared statement (PostgreSQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648861/can-we-use-ddl-commands-in-a-prepared-statement-postgresql)

So, manually sanitising user input is the way to go... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use quotes around the bindings:

```
DB::statement('CREATE USER :username@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY :password;',
               array('username' => 'johndoe', 'password' => 'secret'));
```

Comment: Okay... Just to be sure, if you write it without bindings it works?

Comment: Can you take a look at the query log of your database server?

Comment: Try it without the quotes around `?`

Comment: But I don't think they are when using bindings. Otherwise `?` will be interpreted as string aren't they?