# creating a view: Php->PDO->postgres PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, view

normal select, insert etc work, now i am stuck trying to create a view and there seems to be some problem with the placeholder, if i insert a static number instead of the placeholder the line works... i tryed first without cast, then with implicit cast (::int) and now explicit cast, but it doesn't want to work....

```
$sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW allowedlists AS
         SELECT distinct l.id, l.nom FROM listing as l,acl,user2acl
         WHERE userid=cast(:userid as INTEGER) AND acl.id=aclid 
          and value > (select value from acl where name='saisie');";
$stmt = $csh->handler->pdo->prepare($sql); 
if(!$stmt->bindValue(":userid", $_SESSION["userid"],PDO::PARAM_INT))
             print("failed to bind 'userid = ".$_SESSION["userid"]."' as ".PDO::PARAM_INT." to ".print_r($stmt,true)."<br>\n"); 
else print("bound 'userid' to ".$_SESSION["userid"]." of type '".PDO::PARAM_INT."'<br\n>");
print("before create view<br>\n"); 
if(!($viewcreation = $stmt->execute()))
{   
  print("<p style=\"color:red;\">Error: (".$stmt->errorCode()."): ".print_r($stmt->errorInfo(),true)."</p>\n");
  $stmt->debugDumpParams();  
} 
print("after create view<br>\n");
```

which fails with :

```
before create view(1)<br>
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $1 in <b>/var/www/html/content/listing.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<p style="color:red;">Error: (42P18): Array
(
    [0] => 42P18
    [1] => 7
    [2] => ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $1
)       
</p>    
SQL: [209] CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW allowedlists AS SELECT distinct l.id, l.nom FROM listing as l,acl,user2acl WHERE userid=cast(:userid as INTEGER) AND acl.id=aclid and value > (select value from acl where name='saisie');
Params:  1
Key: Name: [7] :userid
paramno=0
name=[7] ":userid"
is_param=1
param_type=1
after create view<br>
```

seems i am missing the obvious here, but i turn this around and around for 3 days now, but the only thing i manage to build is frustration?

as far as i can see the placeholder binds fine, the type seems good too, as said, if i replace the placeholder with a static number, it works, but not with the placeholder :(

Comment: You can probably drop the `CAST` function of the query, since you're already enforcing an integer on your PDO statement.

Comment: well since it failed, i added the cast, but originally there wasn't one indeed... and since i didn't want to be amiss, i preferred doublingthis over...

Comment: Does the select-only part of the query run correctly under PDO with the `:userid` parameter binding? I guess yes while the DDL statement does not. I suppose this: The select part of the DDL statement is in fact a rule that will be applied later when the view is accessed. So a parameter name that is passed at definition time can not be bound to a value at run time, i.e. the `SELECT` query within a `CREATE VIEW` DDL might not be parameterized.

Comment: See the in-depth answer of @CraigRinger for a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648861/can-we-use-ddl-commands-in-a-prepared-statement-postgresql)

Comment: ok, so short answer is 'not easily' thanks for the answer, i get it for the the creation of tables or the names of columns, i juste, naively?, hoped that since the changing parameter is in the where clause this could work.... but problably you are right, i have to introduce the id statically :( well since i have to add the username to each view, is not really a problem, just have ot make the safe :( a prepared statement would have been more satisfying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creating a VIEW is a DDL operation, similar to creating a table. As such it **cannot** be parameterized. Use then "Parametrize" it by using the parameter is the where clause of the select statement.

```
create or replace view allowedlists as
   select distinct l.id, l.nom 
     from listing as l,acl,user2acl
         where  acl.id=aclid 
          and value > (select value from acl where name='saisie'); 
... 

select id, nom 
  from allowedlists
 where id = :userid; 
 
 OR       

select id, nom 
  from allowedlists
 where id = cast(:userid as integer);
```

Since the where clause is delayed until selecting from the view it may be necessary to add columns to the select creating the view. As you did not alias all columns I cannot tell. A similar approach would be needed to parametrize name, but your select

Comment: unfortunately i wanted to make a table with only the entries that user might see, so creating a view where the user has to be selected defeats the idea :D but thanks anyway, since the parameter was in the where clause i didn't think that it applied to DDL but DML.... so i have to create the create view programmatically escaping the session stored id...